# Read / Write different Microsoft Office file formats using Apache POI

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, xlsx

How to perform different functions on Microsoft Excel spreadsheet using Apache POI ?

I'm trying to generate and update an Excel file ( data from DB ) from my Spring MVC App..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Include apache poi jar file**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

> **To read an excel file**

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
//..
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

//Get iterator to all cells of current row
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
```

The classes we used in above code snippet, **HSSFWorkbook** and **HSSFSheet** works for .xls format. In order to work with  .xlsx use **XSSFWorkbook** and **XSSFSheet** class.

Similar to HSSF, POI has different prefix for other file formats too:

**HSSF (Horrible SpreadSheet Format)** – reads and writes Microsoft Excel (XLS) format files.

**XSSF (XML SpreadSheet Format)** – reads and writes Office Open XML (XLSX) format files.

**HPSF (Horrible Property Set Format)** – reads “Document Summary” formation from Microsoft Office files.

**HWPF (Horrible Word Processor Format)** – aims to read and write Microsoft Word 97 (DOC) format files.

**HSLF (Horrible Slide Layout Format)** – a pure Java implementation for Microsoft PowerPoint files.

**HDGF (Horrible DiaGram Format)** – an initial pure Java implementation for Microsoft Visio binary files.

**HPBF (Horrible PuBlisher Format)** – a pure Java implementation for Microsoft Publisher files.

**HSMF (Horrible Stupid Mail Format)** – a pure Java implementation for Microsoft Outlook MSG files.

**DDF (Dreadful Drawing Format)** – a package for decoding the Microsoft Office Drawing format.

> **Create New Excel File**

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
//..
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FuSsA sheet");
//Create a new row in current sheet
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
//Create a new cell in current row
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
//Set value to new value
cell.setCellValue("Slim Shady");
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = 
                new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\new.xls"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> **Update Existing Excel File**

```
try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\update.xls"));

            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Cell cell = null;

            //Update the value of cell
            cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue() * 2);
            cell = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue() * 2);
            cell = sheet.getRow(3).getCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue() * 2);

            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\update.xls"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For more details, Adding Formulas and  Adding Styles to Cell you can check this link: [Read / Write Excel file in Java using Apache POI](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/)

Answer (score 0):

For manipulation of any cells or adding formula , you can use the folowing:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Calculate Simple Interest");

        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Pricipal Amount (P)");
        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Rate of Interest (r)");
        header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Tenure (t)");
        header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Interest (P r t)");

        Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(1);
        dataRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(14500d);
        dataRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(9.25);
        dataRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(3d);
        dataRow.createCell(3).setCellFormula("A2*B2*C2");

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = 
                    new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\formula.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For adding styles to the cell,

```
you can use: cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

For adding background to cells, you can use the following:

```
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
```